# What is the difference between Cognitive Bias and Cognitive distortion?

Tags: cognitive-psychology, cognitive-neuroscience, cognitive-modeling, bias, cognitive-distortion

I was asked by my professor to give a presentation on the topic ***"Cognitive biases and distortions"*** and during my prep I had this question. Could anyone please shed some light?

I tried finding more regarding the difference but I am yet to find "cognitive biases **vs** distortions" I have only found "cognitive biases **and** distortions".
Going by definitions it seems to me that distortions might be a subset of biases but i'm not at all sure. The counter argument to this for me is maybe biases are more about ***what we see*** and distortions about ***how we interpret it*** .

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wikipedia has articles on both of these terms, so that would be one place to start. Although you may not be able to cite Wikipedia as a source, both of these articles have good References sections.

Here are the Wikipedia definitions (emphasis added):

- [Cognitive bias](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cognitive_bias): "a systematic pattern of deviation from norm or rationality in judgment."
- [Cognitive distortion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cognitive_distortion): "an exaggerated or irrational thought pattern **involved in the onset or perpetuation of psychopathological states**, such as depression and anxiety."

So both of these terms apply to thought patterns that deviate from a theoretical rational standard. But cognitive distortions apply specifically to states considered psychologically abnormal, while cognitive biases refer to properties of human thinking that tend to affect everyone. The examples given in the articles seem to support this distinction.

As you mentioned, cognitive distortions could be seen as a subset of cognitive biases, specifically the subset that leads to psychopathological conditions.

Comment: I had an idea, maybe **biases** are about us ignoring a part of the total information or facts available and **distortions** are about us interpreting or processing the availlable facts in the wrong way.  ANY COMMENTS??

Comment: @user14812745 I don't think that distinction is generally true. For example, *confirmation bias* is a type of cognitive bias in which people tend to promote information that confirms their preconceptions and discredit information that goes against their beliefs. So they acknowledge the available information, but they interpret information differently depending on whether it supports their argument.

Comment: Yup I understand your viewpoint , appreciate your effort trying to answer my question.